# Почему в твиттере ruSO последний пост от Мая 2018?

Tags: дефект, поддержка

Заглянул в [твиттер](https://twitter.com/ruStackOverflow) и обнаружил, что там посты кончаются маем 2018 (если я ничего не путаю). Раньше вроде топовые вопросы автоматически публиковались в твиттере - что случилось, почему перестали?

Answer (score 5):

Задавался этим же вопросом [пару лет назад в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48893824#48893824).

Небольшая выдержка из последующей переписки в чате (**N** - Nicolas Chabanovsky, **A** - αλεχολυτ):

> **N**: Если честно, я совершенно не помню.
> **A**: так может надо вернуть?
> **N**: Возможно. Правда, я не очень понимаю зачем. Думаете, кто–то читает роболенту?
> **A**: Ну подписчики же есть у аккаунта. Да и на enSO тоже. Правда там по меткам есть учетные записи, что несколько специфичнее, а потому более востребовано.
> **N**: Мне роболента кажется бесполезной, прямо совсем.
> Я даже думаю, что без роболенты лучше. Зачем интернеты захламлять.
> Одно дело, мы прям дико чем–то хотим поделиться с остальным миром, каким–нибудь крутым вопросом или ответом, или инициативной на Мете и тд, другое алгоритмичненько публикуем все подряд. Что вы думаете по поводу робо-твиттер-лент?
> **A**: так ведь публикуется не всё подряд, а топовые по голосам. Я например подписан на ленту enSO по c++. И это удобнее бывает смотреть, чем заходить непосредственно на сайт и там выводить hot questions
> **N**: Это вроде бы решается подпиской на метку и RSS лентой?
> **A**: у меня нет rss клиента активного. А твиттер есть.

Таким образом, напрашивается, следующий вывод: публикации в твиттер отключены по причине бесполезности.

Comment: Я бы уточнил, отключены не по причине просто "бесполезности", а по причине "бесполезности с точки зрения КМ".

Comment: Странно, а чего они тогда рассылку не отключили. Я на почту её регулярно получаю.

Comment: 43 подписчика за все время, и абсолютно нулевая активность на твитах. какой смысл это оживлять :(